# Issue with variable closure initialization issue

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, closures

In my class, I have a property that is a sort of audioPlayer and I am planning to do the setup job in a closure as this:

```
var urlPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Focus", withExtension: "mp3")!

var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = { var player =  try! AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: urlPath)

    return player }()
```

> Instance member 'urlPath' cannot be used on type 'BackgroundAudio'

[image]

I don't quite understand what is wrong with my code? How to resolve this, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rob Moderator election of this year on stack overflow nomination phase is going on wish you to see there as moderator nominee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import AudioToolbox 
 import AVFoundation

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Focus", withExtension: "mp3")!

    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let player = player else { return }

        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.description)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a syntax error in your code. As `audioPlayer` is a computed property, you should not have `=`.

The following

```
var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = { var player =  try! AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: urlPath)

    return player }()
```

should be written as

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer {
    var player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: urlPath)
    return player
}
```

Comment: That's nicer, but it doesn't address the root of the OPs problem, methinks.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, it's saying that it cannot use the other stored property during initialization, because it doesn't know if it is initialized or not. As [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID232) says:

> If you use a closure to initialize a property, remember that the rest of the instance has not yet been initialized at the point that the closure is executed. This means that you cannot access any other property values from within your closure, even if those properties have default values. You also cannot use the implicit `self` property, or call any of the instance’s methods.

You can resolve this by making audioPlayer a `lazy` var, so the initialization is deferred until you first use it, resolving the ambiguity. E.g.

```
var urlPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Focus", withExtension: "mp3")!
lazy var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: self.urlPath)
```

Or if you don't need this `URL` reference elsewhere, you can just have a single constant:

```
let audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = {
    var urlPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Focus", withExtension: "mp3")!
    return try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: urlPath)
}()
```

Lots of options. The key is that you can't have a simple stored property initializing itself using another property's value. You need someway to resolve the ambiguity, such as the two above approaches.